# Form not hidden on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

On my site http://purewords.com/site16/ if you scroll down to the bottom of the page you will see the contact form that is supposed to be hidden. However if you click on "contact" in the menu then on the cross to close the pop-up box, then the form does no longer appear at the bottom.
How can I make the form invisible on page loading?
Many thanks,

Comment: Please don't obfuscate your URLs, there's no per-character charge for a well-formed question =) (really, we like to know where we're going. Especially those of us answering while at work.)

Comment: Have you tried setting its `display` to `none`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the contact form's wrapper `display:none`

```css
#inline {
    display: none;
}
```

Also, your form is broken, having two closing `form` tags:

```
    <button id="send">Send E-mail</button></form>
</form>
```